# Typescript, No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this function:

```
const fieldsOrder = [
  'boo',
];

fieldsOrder.reduce((sortedRequest, key) => {
  if (key in request)
    sortedRequest[key] = request[key]; // Here are the warnings
  return sortedRequest;
}
```

`sortedRequest` is an object, same with `request`, so I'm having that warning about using index in objects. In plain javascript works ok, how could I handle and modify the code to not have that warning?

I can't define `sortedRequest` or `request` as `any` or anything using `any` type, or Elinst will thrown an error (I can't changes that rule neither).

EDIT:

I've tried what tscpp answered. This is my code now:

```
export default function sortFields (
  request: Record<string, unknown>
): Partial<FeeLookupRequest> {
  return fieldsOrder.reduce((sortedRequest: Record<string, unknown>, key) => {
    if (key in request) {
      sortedRequest[key] = request[key];
    }
    return sortedRequest;
  }, {});
}
```

Now has no warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `fieldsOrder` is the type `{}`. The type `{}` have no keys. You need to type fieldsOrder with e.g `object` or `Record<string, unknown>` preferably.

Comment: I forgot to put what `fieldsOrder` is. I've edited my question. Did you mean `sortedRequest`?